# Did Donnie Decker exist and could he make it rain at will?

Tags: weather

According to this website: [10 Enigmas](http://listverse.com/2010/01/14/10-more-enigmas-that-defy-explanation/), there was a boy called "Donnie Decker" (number 1 on the list in the website), born in 1983, who could make it rain at will.

Here is an extract from that story:

> Dubbed the Rain Boy in 1983, Donnie Decker ..... complained, Donnie explained that he could make it rain when he wanted to, and proved his point by dumping rain on the jailor on duty. Eventually, he was released from jail and found a job as a cook at a local restaurant. His present whereabouts is unknown – as is the cause of the mysterious rain.

While most of the stories on this list are semi-believable or seem to have some basis in fact, I find this one very hard to swallow.

Surely someone with this kind of ability would not only be more well-known, but have been studied further by medical / government / military institutions?

This sounds incredibly far-fetched and I'm wondering where they're getting this information form. Did such a person really exist? Could he (can he still) make it rain at will?

Various versions of his story have been repeated on [many](http://www.ghosttheory.com/2013/03/03/don-decker-poltergeist) [paranormal](http://unsolved.com/archives/don-decker) [sites](http://beforeitsnews.com/strange/2013/12/donny-decker-the-rain-man-demon-possessed-teleknisis-or-hoax-2453368.html), including [a longer version at Historic Mysteries](http://www.historicmysteries.com/don-decker-rain-man/):

Comment: One of the pages you link to (Historic Mysteries) explicitly says that it was involuntary, and never happened again after a Reverend prayed with him and the rain stopped.  Doesn't address the question of whether or not it happened in the first place, though.

Comment: Also, someone with the same name, in the same general area of PA, and a reasonably appropriate age (would have been 23 in 1983) is accused of [burning down a restaurant](http://wnep.com/2012/10/16/restaurant-owner-facing-arson-charges/) in 2011.

Comment: Richard Wolbert (one of the patrolmen from the article) is now [a corporal in the Stroud Area Regional Police](http://www.sarpd.com/index.php/staff-directory), so the photo of the officers associated with the story may, in fact, be him.  On the other hand, that police force wasn't formed until 2000, and didn't have a building until 2003, so the picture is *not* contemporary to the story.